# PHP reverse generator without array

Tags: php, generator

I have generator:

```
function f() {
  foreach(range(1, 100) as $i) { 
    yield i;
  }
}
```

Is there elegant way to make another function when I pass the generator to reverse it.

I dont want to use array since I want to be able to slice the new generator(reverse) without looping all elements.

For example:

```
function reverseGen(gen) {...}
```

Comment: Please give us some examples of what you mean by _"reverse generator"_. What's the expected result from what input?

Comment: numbres from 100 to 1 decremented by 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no intrinsic “end” to a generator, e.g. `while (true) yield $i++;`. There’s also no way to access a specific element of a generator, nor to ask a generator for its previous value. The only thing you can do with a generator is to ask for its next value, and once you’ve done that, that value is gone and you can’t access it again.

So, no, there’s no way to iterate a generator in reverse; all you can do is store its values in an array and iterate that in reverse.